# Окно редактирования настроек

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Setting1 {get;set;}
}
public class SettinngViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public SettingViewModel(Setting settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    Setting _settings {get; private set;}

    public string Setting1
    {
        get {return setting1;}
        set {setting1=value; OnPropertyChanged("Setting1")}
    }
}
```

собственно вопрос в следующем: есть главная форма из которой вызывается данное окно редактирования настроек

```
public MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(x=>SettingsMethod());
    }

    var currentSettings = //здесь хранятся текущие настройки

    public ICommand SettingsCommand {get; private set;}

    private void SettingsMethod()
    {
        var view = new SettingsView();
        view.DataContext = new SettingsViewModel(currentSettings);
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

ввиду того что `settings` это ссылочный тип то при изменении в окне настроек изменения сразу отражаются в главной форме, а я бы хотел что бы это было только после подтверждения(например пользователь нажимает кнопку *Применить*)

помогите реализовать соответствующую команду

Comment: Ну тут спорный вопрос, сейчас такая тенденция, что настройки да и  любые данные применяются мгновенно, без всяких лишних кнопок "Применить". Такова новая мода. Но если уж хочется сделать по кнопке, то лучше завести модель, которая будет переливать настройки по клику

Comment: @Dmitry ну может пример с настройками неудачен, может быть любой другой объект который необходимо менять только по подтверждению:)

Comment: ну я уже написал :) нужно отдельную модель, и из нее значения передавать в нужный объект, правда я так понимаю принципы MVVM нарушаться, которые нехотелось бы нарушать. не так ли?

Comment: @Dmitry Вы правы насчет *принципов которые не хотелось бы нарушать*, насчет отдельной модели не уверен, я думаю о создании копии объекта и передаче его в форму редактирования настроек, тогда при изменении в форме изменения не коснуться *главного объекта* но вот как это все сделать *правильно* не знаю:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите.

Если вы редактируете настройки, вы редактируете, понятно, *копию* настроек, а не *оригинал*. В WinForms это скрывалось за тем фактом, что применение изменений происходило во View, но с WPF/MVVM правильный подход такой.

Рассмотрим случай, когда у вас *нет* VM-объекта, отвечающего за настройки, который поддерживает свои поля в актуальном состоянии. Тогда вам нужен VM-объект «редактируемые настройки» (`SettingsEditorVM`), который при старте считывает свои свойства из модельного объекта, но не синхронизирует их с моделью при изменениях. Он также выставляет команду «окончить редактирование», по приходу которой проверяет настройки на правильность, и если они в порядке, записывает результат в модельный объект.

Для случая, когда у вас уже есть VM-объект, отвечающий за настройки (`SettingsVM`), который поддерживает свои поля в актуальном состоянии, вам нужно всё равно завести ещё один VM-объект «редактируемые настройки» (`SettingsEditorVM`), который сможет загрузить данные (например, в конструкторе) из `SettingsVM`, и по команде закончить редактирование.

Этим можно пользоваться так:

```
public class SettinngEditorVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public SettinngEditorVM(SettingVM settingsVM)
    {
        FinishedEditing = new AwaitableCommand();
        CancelledEditing = new AwaitableCommand();
        Setting1 = settingsVM.Setting1;
    }

    string setting1;
    public string Setting1
    {
        get { return setting1; }
        set
        {
            setting1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Setting1");
            CheckCorrectness();
        }
    }

    void CheckCorrectness()
    {
        bool ok = Setting1 != null;
        FinishedEditing.CanExecuteInternal = ok;
    }

    public AwaitableCommand FinishEditing { get; private set; }
    public AwaitableCommand CancelledEditing { get; private set; }

    public async Task<bool> Edit()
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var finished = FinishEditing.TillActivation(CancellationToke.None);
            var cancelled = CancelledEditing.TillActivation(CancellationToke.None);
            var winner = await Task.WhenAny(finished, cancelled);
            cts.Cancel();
            await winner;
            return winner == finished;
        }
    }
}
```

с таким вызовом:

```
var editorVM = new SettingsEditorVM(editorVM);
var task = editorVM.Edit();
var editorWindow = new EditorWindow() { DataContext = editorVM };
editorWindow.Show();
var succeeded = await task;
if (succeeded)
    settingsVM.LoadFrom(editorVM);
```

---

Заметьте, что код у `SettingsEditorVM` и `SettingsVM` практически одинаков, так что эти два класса стоит объединить в один.

---

Вот код `AwaitableCommand`:

```
class AwaitableCommand : ICommand
{
    bool canExecute;

    // не придумал названия получше
    public bool CanExecuteInternal
    {
        get
        {
            return canExecute;
        }
        set
        {
            if (canExecute == value)
                return;
            canExecute = value;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        foreach (var tcs in subscribers)
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        subscribers.Clear();
    }

    List<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> subscribers = new List<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();

    public async Task TillActivation(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        subscribers.Add(tcs);
        using (ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled()))
            await tcs.Task;
    }
}
```