# Внутренний ShowDialog

Tags: wpf, функции, page

Есть приложение на WPF. Соответственно основное окно и из этого окна необходимо вызвать блок элементов после взаимодействия с которым необходимо вернуть определенный обьект (Что то похожее на проводник-рекдактор). На данный момент этот "Проводник" "упакован" в UserControl и вызывлся обходными путями на форму и читается событиями. В общем достаточно криво. Ренее в другом приложении в подобных ситуациях использовал новое окно, ShowDialog и статическая функция Show возврашаюшая необходимый результат.  Но в данном случае нужно сделать некое всплываюшее окно внутри родительского окна. Вроде есть какая-то PageFunction, но не понимаю подойдёт ли оно для такой задачи, и можно ли из него получать данные аналогично с ShowDialog? Причём важно чтобы не блокировались паралельные потоки, запущенные в главном окне.

Comment: `ShowDialog` — это кривой хак на отсутствие в старых версиях async/await. Делайте правильно, через Task. Вот пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471030/10105

Comment: `<Popup ...>` не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

На основе примера из комментария про ShowDialog, сделал немного по своему, так как мне всё же нужно не отдельное окно. Вызываю контрол в Таргет контэйнер и ожидаю результата.

```
    bool IsReturn = false;
    object returnedObj = false;


    public async static Task<object> Get(Grid TargetContainer)
    {
        object obj = null;
        FilterDispatcher WFD = new FilterDispatcher();
        int ThisIndex = TargetContainer.Children.Add(WFD);
        while (!WFD.IsReturn)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        obj = WFD.returnedObj;
        TargetContainer.Children.RemoveAt(ThisIndex);
        return obj;
    }
```

Вызываю примерно необходимым способом

```
    await FilterDispatcher.Get(contenGrid)
```